# How to add prefix to all root attributes xml in x++ ax 2012

Tags: xml, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to export information to xml in x++.  I would like to have the end result look like this below.  this is the root node.
The issue is I don't get the pidx: prefix showing infront of all the attributes.
For example if I have code like this

```
 xmlRoot = xmlDoc.createElement3(pidx, "Invoice", namespace);
```

it will produce the result

```
<pidx:Invoice xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0">
```

which is fine but when i add attributes

```
xmlRoot.setAttribute("transactionPurposeIndicator","Original");
```

it leaves out the pidx: that is suppose to be infront of transactionPurposeIndicator
thus not giving me the expected output below.
Even if i add pidx: infront of the transactionPurposeIndicator it ignores it. How can i have it show for all attributes as this is the root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <pidx:Invoice pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator="Original" pidx:version="1.0" xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.0 http://banff.digitaloilfield.com/XML/OI-PIDX-Invoice.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `xmlRoot.setAttribute2("transactionPurposeIndicator", namespace, "Original");` instead of `xmlRoot.setAttribute("transactionPurposeIndicator","Original");` This will give the expected result.